# How to get data based on combination of strings?

Tags: mysql

I have table records with data,

```
id, title
1, This is test the thunder
2, This is test
3, This is Testing
4, whatever
5, this is alkdjlsad asdjasjdlad
6, test
7, thunder
```

I want a query in such a way that, it will fetch all records except 2, 3 and 6
Explanation: 2nd 3rd and 6th record contain the only test, 1st record contains test but with thunder.

If any record with 'test' and 'thunder' exists to accept such record,
but if purely with 'test' then ignore such record,

**Expected output**:

```
id, title
1, This is test the thunder
4, whatever
5, this is alkdjlsad asdjasjdlad
7, thunder
```

I can't think beyond what is my expectations.

Please help me create this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `REGEXP` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    title NOT REGEXP 'test' OR
    (title REGEXP 'test' AND title REGEXP '[[:<:]]thunder[[:>:]]');
```

[image]

### Demo

The logic here is to find any record whose title does not contain the *substring* `test`, or contains `test`, but also contains `thunder`.  My gut reaction was to put word boundaries around `test`, but it looks like you actually just want to find the substring `test` anywhere in the title.

Comment: Done. Thanks. I actually wasn't sure what to search so posted the question. You are saviour.

Comment: @rahulsm I changed my answer, because it looks like you are trying to search for the substring `test` anywhere in the title.  I'm not sure you actually want to do this, but in any case my answer now reflects this requirement.